# Reordering html elements within different containers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, responsive

i try to reorder my items after a specific logic and couldnt get it done with css grid.
i have this html structure:

```
<div class="multi-column-row">
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 1</div>
    <div>ITEM 2</div>
    <div>ITEM 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 4</div>
    <div>ITEM 5</div>
    <div>ITEM 6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 7</div>
    <div>ITEM 8</div>
    <div>ITEM 9</div>
</div>
</div>
```

On Desktop the rows are displayed horizontaly so it looks like this:

```
ITEM 1 | ITEM 4 | ITEM 7
ITEM 2 | ITEM 5 | ITEM 8
ITEM 3 | ITEM 6 | ITEM 9
```

Now what i want to achieve is following on mobile when the rows are display verticaly:

```
ITEM 1
ITEM 4
ITEM 7
ITEM 2
ITEM 5
ITEM 8
ITEM 3
ITEM 6
ITEM 9
```

And it has to work even when they are more ore less items in the columns.
Before you ask why i dont put the items directly in this order and have three rows with 3 columns each :) is because on desktop i need 3 columns with multiple items inside like a masonry grid.

i appreciate every help even a javascript solution to reorder dom elements

Comment: Only js will help here.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov can you help me with the js solution?

Comment: Yes, i can help

Comment: *And it has to work even when they are more ore less items in the columns* --> and how it supposed to work in case you have for example 2 elements in the first column and 5 in the second? you need to define a clear behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not scale well but it is possible using flexbox and `display:contents` and then ordering the contents of the `.row` divs.

```css
.multi-column-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.multi-column-row .row {
  display: contents;
}

.multi-column-row .row :nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

.multi-column-row .row :nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

.multi-column-row .row :nth-child(3) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-column-row">
  <div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 1</div>
    <div>ITEM 2</div>
    <div>ITEM 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 4</div>
    <div>ITEM 5</div>
    <div>ITEM 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 7</div>
    <div>ITEM 8</div>
    <div>ITEM 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile display example repeats `ITEM 3`. I thought this was a mistake. I think it must be `ITEM 2` ?!

In my example, the `row` classes are deleted, and then the elements are ordered by means of media queries.

I wrapped all the logic in the `onresize` event. This is done to visually understand the principle of operation when changing the browser window. In production, it needs to be replaced with a window `onload` event. Like that:

```
window.onload = function() {
   ... 
}
```

Logic in js is triggered from `767 pixels` of the screen.

Was such a result necessary?

```js
window.onresize = function() {
  let media = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)");
  let unwrap_div = document.querySelectorAll('.multi-column-row .row');

  if (media.matches) {
    unwrap_div.forEach(function(unwrap_div_curr) {
      unwrap_div_curr.outerHTML = unwrap_div_curr.innerHTML;
    })
  } else {} 
}
```

```css
.multi-column-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {

  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(2) {
    order: 7;
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(3) {
    order: 4;
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(4) {
    order: 2;
  
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(5) {
    order: 5;
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(6) {
    order: 8; 
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(7) {
    order: 3; 
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(8) {
    order: 6;
  }
  
  .multi-column-row div:nth-child(9) {
    order: 9;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-column-row">
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 1</div>
    <div>ITEM 2</div>
    <div>ITEM 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 4</div>
    <div>ITEM 5</div>
    <div>ITEM 6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>ITEM 7</div>
    <div>ITEM 8</div>
    <div>ITEM 9</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add media queries (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  list-style-type: none;
}
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Contact us</li>
  <li>Report</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using display as inline and inline block you can change. Also if you add media query to the logic, based on the screen width the layout will change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
            .row {
                display: inline;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 480px)  {
            .row {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="multi-column-row">
        <div class="row">
            <div>ITEM 1</div>
            <div>ITEM 2</div>
            <div>ITEM 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>ITEM 4</div>
            <div>ITEM 5</div>
            <div>ITEM 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>ITEM 7</div>
            <div>ITEM 8</div>
            <div>ITEM 9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: aah you ask is wrong it should be  ITEM 1
ITEM 4
ITEM 7
ITEM 2
ITEM 5
ITEM 8
ITEM 3
ITEM 6
ITEM 9